# Returning a char array from C++ function to tcl

Tags: c++, arrays, tcl

I have seen a similar question, but have been unable to get the desired result.  I need to call a c++ function and have the function pass an array to tcl.  My current structure is:

```
    Tcl_Obj *     result = Tcl_NewObj();
    unsigned char *buffer = Tcl_SetByteArrayLength(result, 16);
    //some other code

    //I2C function that fills the buffer
    sub_i2c_read(handles[handle], theI2cAddr, 0, 0, (char*)buffer, theNumToRead

    //more code
    //try to place data in tcl
    Tcl_SetObjResult(theInterp, result);
```

I have been able to see that the buffer has the desired content within c++, but the variable I am trying to set it to in tcl is empty.

I am trying to call it like this:

```
    set result [sub20 read  $hand "70" 3]
```

My current thought process is that this makes the tcl object, turns it into a byte array using 'buffer' as a pointer to the byte array, and then sets the data in tcl, but that is clearly flawed.
Any further clarification on this would be appreciated.

Comment: A byte array has no implicit meaning in Tcl. It is not a string and you are not supposed to be viewing it.

Comment: @n.m. So should I be looking for a way to convert it to a string in Tcl?

Comment: How are you determining that the result is empty? Using binary scan?

Comment: If you want a string, perhaps use Tcl_StringObj and friends, rather than Tcl_ByteArray on the C++ side. If you do need binary data, and only want to convert it to a string for debugging, use e.g. `binary encode base64` on the Tcl side.

Comment: @Austin Mullins I was initially just trying to 'puts' the content in tcl, but I am now aware that was incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That C++ code looks fine. The bytes should be in the buffer just fine, and the buffer should have been transferred to Tcl's ownership and stored in the variable just fine. You can double-check that by using `string length $result` to see how many bytes are in there; Tcl considers byte arrays to be a string of characters in the range U+000000 to U+0000FF, so string operations work transparently.

What you probably can't do is just print it out. Byte arrays from various protocols often contain lots of nulls (U+000000, NUL, `\000`, `\x00`, `\u0000`, etc.) and they do not print well. Instead, to understand the content, use the `binary` command to parse the bytes. For example:

```
binary scan $result i2d ints dble
```

That will take that 16 byte buffer and read two little-endian 32-bit ints out of it (storing them in a two-element Tcl list in the `ints` variable) and then an IEEE double-precision float in the current platform's native representation (storing it in the `dble` variable). The `i2d` is the format descriptor; there are *many* format characters supported in there, and you'll have to read the documentation carefully to get exactly what you want. However, the variables will be holding conventional Tcl values afterwards (the actual result of `binary scan` is the number of format characters — excluding modifiers like `2` — successfully processed, which ought to be two in this example).

Comment: You are correct.  The code was working properly, I just had a stupid mistake in the trivial part after that I had overlooked.  Thanks for taking the time to explain the details on the inner workings of the binary scan command, that will be very useful!